# Select element with class name that starts with using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have some classes which are dynamically generated in React. They always have the same prefix but they all end differently

How can I use Cypress to select a class name that begins with X?

```
<div class="this-is-always-the-same-abcd"></>
<div class="this-is-always-the-same-efgh"></>
<div class="this-is-always-the-same-ijkl"></>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to their **[Best Practices Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements)**, you should use **`data-*`** attributes to provide context to your selectors and insulate them from CSS or JS changes.

It's suggested that you follow these guidelines:

- Don’t target elements based on CSS attributes such as: **`id`**, **`class`**, **`tag`**.
- Don’t target elements that may change their **`textContent`**.
- Add **`data-*`** attributes to make it easier to target elements.

Instead, you should add a **`data-cy`** attribute to target the selector that you're testing.

You can use **[this playground](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Selector-Playground)** to determine an unique selector.

Comment: Yes, that is recommended, but sometimes it is not the case that you can use data-* attribute (For example when you do not have full control over specific part)

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 61):

To everyone who really need to target class and cannot (Or do not want) use `data-` attributes for some reasons. Solution is to use standard css selector.

```js
cy.get('*[class^="this-is-always-the-same"]')
```

This will get all elements that has class starting with `this-is-always-the-same`.

Comment: Selecting `class`'s names is highly discouraged because it creates flaky tests.

Comment: @Manuel Abascal Yes, I'm not encouraging anyone to use classes as main way to look up elements (as mentioned in answer. But there are edge cases, when you basically cannot use data attributes (for example part of HTML output is rendered by library you do not have control of)

Comment: Getting back to this after a while. We've been using Cypress extensively for tests and I see now why class names are discouraged. We use react css modules and the classnames are never the same + developers has a tendency to rename classes or restructure layouts so we opted for data- selectors almost exclusively. 
Much more stable that way + savvy QA engineers can add their own hooks if they need them.  :)

Comment: @AdrianE we also use data attributes, as classes in our cases doesn't even cover all options, but I want to point out, that there are edge cases, for example when we used react-select, and we needed to manipulate it in cypress - no other way around than using classes

Comment: at the same time, if you want to pick a date/time using MUI Pickers, you don't have much choice...

Answer (score 11):

Thanks [@SergeS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849612/6904888), your answer was really helpful to me. Just let me add that it works with any kind of tag, so this is also valid

```
cy.get('*[data-cy^="introCard"]')
```

Where 'introCard' in my case, is only the beginning of some longer words

Answer (score 0):

I need to check if button is disabled, which is using framework specific class, but none of the answers was working for me, so I used `invoke()` to get all classes and after that I check class I was interested in is present.

```
cy.get('[data-cy=uiButton]').invoke('attr', 'class').then($classNames => {
  // classNames is string but can be converted to array and iterated over like classNames.split(' ')
  if (!$classNames.includes('Button_disabled')) {
    throw new Error(`No class found "Button_disabled" in ${$classNames}`);
  }
});
```